# Connected Apps: Is the request to my server made Salesforce or directly by the browser?

Tags: connected-apps

My connected apps are all up and running. But a network snafu broke something for some of our internal clients and now I'm confused.

My connected app is hosted at company.com/app.

When I'm looking at a Contact, and I see the HTML for my connected app, did my browser go directly to company.com/app, or did Salesforce connect there on my behalf, and then return the HTML by proxy?

Comment: See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_sso_id_provider.htm. Salesforce is just handling the authentication with the identity provider. Which one you're using for SSO or SAML is difficult to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser directly connects to the resource; basically, salesforce creates an auto-submitted POST form that goes to your app with the various resources it needs (e.g. token, signatures, etc). The only step that salesforce is involved in is creating a signed request and passing that to your app. After that, your browser and the service interact directly.